# how we develop a functionality in the flutter where when we hover the camera on any object and it scan the image

Tags: flutter

I want to ask a query related to the flutter scanning object.
For example if i want to hover the camera on any objects and it scans the object without clicking the capture the image.
thanks

as mention above, i need answer above question